# Cron Job not executing in centos 7

Tags: python, bash, cron

I have created a shell script which i want to schedule using **cronjob**.
I used command `crontab -e` and then i wrote `* * * * * /xxxx/xxx/workflow.sh`
After that i typed `:wq!`. I got a message saying `crontab: installing new crontab` but nothing happens after that. I tried running my workflow.sh separately and it is working fine. Below is my workflow.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "script started"
python /xxxx/xxx/move_files.py

echo "Training Started"
for N in {1..9}; do /xxxx/xxx/openface-master/util/align-dlib.py /xxxx/xxx/openface-master/training_dataset align outerEyesAndNose /xxxx/xxx/openface-master/aligned_data --size 96 & done

/xxxx/xxx/openface-master/batch-represent/main.lua -outDir /xxxx/xxx/openface-master/feature -data /xxxx/xxx/openface-master/aligned_data

/xxxx/xxx/openface-master/demos/classifier_original.py train feature

echo "Model running"
/xxxx/xxx/openface-master/demos/classifier_updated.py
```

Please help. I tried removing the file.lock as per suggestion but still it is not working.

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog` to see if there are any messages about it.

Comment: If `file.lock` is actually preventing the job from running, and you create it but never remove it, I think we have found a bug

Comment: @tripleee i tried removing that line where i am creating the lock file using `touch` but still the issue is there.

Comment: @Barmar i couldn't able to find `/var/log/syslog` there is no file as syslog

Comment: What OS are you running? Different Linux distributions use different log files.

Comment: @Barmar i am using centos 7

Comment: [Where to find crontab logs in centos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176229/where-to-find-the-crontab-logs-in-centos)

Comment: We have no idea what this lock file does or doesn't do without looking at the Python code. The way the question is articulated now, only you can determine what its purpose is. Your response indicates that maybe you don't know either.

Comment: @tripleee file.lock i used only to check wether my cronjob is working or not. My shell script worked fine when i am running it separately but not working when i am using cronjob to schedule it. I cannot share my python code as per company policies.

Comment: If you want this question to be reopened, please [edit] to clarify what troubleshooting steps you have taken. The duplicate question and [the Stack Overflow `crontab` tag info page](/tags/crontab/info) have common troubleshooting steps which you need to perform and document in order to make this a unique and hopefully properly answerable question.